# Have log returns series almost always conditional mean zero? I presume no

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, garch, finance

I'm analyzing S&P500 stocks daily log-returns on the 505 time series of the biggest companies in the USA between 2014-01-01 and 2019-12-01.

My task was to identify the ARMA-GARCH model of them.

Fistly i ran Ljung-Box test, and only 44 of them seem to have some kind of (very weak) autocorrelation. For the remaining 461 I fitted an ARMA(0,0)+GARCH(p,q) and this seems to be ok, I can predict reasonably well volatility.

Considering the 44 autocorrelated ts' ARMA component, I can see that ~40 of log-returns doesn't seem to fit in any relevant ARMA(p,q) + $\mu$ (I tried with auto.arima in R but also checked ACF and PACF before), meanwhile GARCH fit with ARMA(0,0)+GARCH(1,1) is great.

Is this possible? No ARMA effect (zero conditional mean, no correlation with the return of the day before, only i.i.d shocks everyday) in daily returns for S&P500? I presume I'm doing something wrong, but the ACF and PACF don't lie: i can see zero autocorrelation almost everywhere. I really can't explain this.

Comment: you cannot make easy money in stock market. Markets are quite efficient when conditioned on past prices. You need insider information. Then you will get non zero conditional mean.

Comment: So, modelling ARMA models for log-returns is in general quite useless almost always? There is any empirical macro-study on the zero conditional mean in financial ts?

Comment: There is a huge literature under “empirical finance” where it is full of examples for inefficiencies when conditioned on company accounting data, time of year, etc. But past price conditioning died long time ago. There used to be non-zero acf in 1960s. Long story short markets are a big casino where the organizers and people with inside info or immense resources make money.